# ¿Cómo comprobar que un dato es un Int?

Tags: java, excepciones

Tengo un pequeño problema en Java. Para un ejercicio, he hecho una aplicación con clases y objetos que crea contraseñas de forma aleatoria si se le da una longitud, que será un entero.
El problema surge porque estoy empezando con el tema de las excepciones y tengo que comprobar que no se den errores. Por supuesto, si el usuario mete una longitud que sea, en realidad, un String (por ejemplo, introduce "patata"), salta la excepción InputMismatchException.
Entonces, la he capturado y utilizado para una opción en que el usuario puede crear 5 contraseñas aleatorias cuando le entregue una longitud. Sin embargo, hay otra opción en que puede crear solo UNA contraseña aleatoria. Ahí surge el problema, porque no me deja repetir la excepción.

Como contexto, le creo un menú con un Switch. La opción 1 es para crear una sola contraseña:

```
System.out.println("Indica la longitud de la contraseña:");
                longitud = teclado.nextInt();
                try{
                    contraseña = new Contraseña(longitud);
                    System.out.println("La contraseña es " + contraseña.getContraseña());
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    System.err.println("ERROR. La longitud no puede ser menor a 7");
                }
```

Había pensado en aprovechar la Exception e —que nace de un método estático aplicado al constructor— para que compruebe si el parámetro longitud es igual a un entero, pero no sé cómo hacerlo.

¿Alguien puede echarme una mano? ¡Gracias!

Comment: ya intentaste usando expresiones regulares?

Answer (score 1):

Habria que capturar un NumberFormatException para validar que el valor ingresado como String sea un numero

```
static boolean isNumeric(String cadena){
    try {
        Integer.parseInt(cadena);
        return true;
    } catch (NumberFormatException exception){
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Podrías agregarle un `catch` que detecte la excepcion `NumberFormatException` antes de la excepcion general `Exception` y meter el input de la contraseña dentro del `try`.

```java
System.out.println("Indica la longitud de la contraseña:");

try {
    longitud = teclado.nextInt();
    contrasena = new Contrasena(longitud);
    System.out.println("La contraseña es " + contrasena.getContrasena());

} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    System.err.println("ERROR. Solo puede introducir caracteres numericos");

} catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println("ERROR. La longitud no puede ser menor a 7");
}
```

También podrías almacenar el input en un `String`, usar una expresión regular como la siguiente y luego castearlo a `int`

```java
final String text = teclado.next();
if (!Pattern.matches("[a-zA-Z]+", text) && text.length() < 7) {
    final int number = Integer.parseInt(text); 
    final contrasena = new Contrasena(number);

} else if (text.length() >= 7) {
    System.err.println("ERROR. La longitud no puede ser menor a 7");

} else {
    System.err.println("ERROR. Solo puede introducir caracteres numericos");
}
```

> Te recomiendo no usar **ñ**, usa la letra **n** en su lugar